# How can I make a ruby gem's binary file act as rackup?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rack

I have a gem. It can optionally be run as a command line app `myapp_cli`, or as an app with a local web ui `myapp_web`.

When working on my app, I can run `bundle exec myapp_cli` for the command line UI, or
I can run `bundle exec rackup` for the web UI.

Now I'd like `bin/myapp_web` to essentially be a synonym for rackup. So when someone installs my gem, they can just run `myapp_cli` or `myapp_web`.

Is there a nice way of doing that?

I can make my `myapp_web` look like

```
Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run(
      App.new,
      :Port => 9000
  )
```

but that doesn't give me all the goodies that rackup gives me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was browse the source.

```
require 'rack'
Rack::Server.start
```